# Get data between last 7 days and last 24 hours MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If i want to get last 24 hours from my server i am using:

```
WHERE table.createdate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

That works. Now i am trying to get last 7 days. While i am doing this i dont want to get last 24 hours. In other words i want to get last `7 day-today`. How can i do that? I tried:

```
WHERE table.createdate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND table.createdate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 168 HOUR) //didnot work
```

**NOTE:** Please pay attention i want result in DATETIME not just DATE.

Comment: It looks fine to me. In what way is it not working for you?

Comment: @Racil Hilan it returns false

Comment: An sql query like this can't return false. But a call to some mysql_ function in PHP can return false because you aren't really connected to the database.

Comment: Returns false? Edit your question and add the full query and some sample data, so we can create a fiddle for you. I think your query is fine and should work as you want.

Comment: sorry i mean it gets 0 data not false

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
WHERE table.createdate <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND table.createdate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
```

?